# How many processes are created with these fork() calls?

Tags: c, fork

How I can see how many processes have been created? Can I use the `getpid()` function?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4;
    pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 != 0) {
      pid2 = fork();
      pid3 = fork();
    } 
    else {
      pid4 = fork();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love homework questions,  Bung in a sleep

Comment: Is the answer 8 - I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fork()` for pid1: One subprocess created.

Number of processes = 2

`fork()` for pid2: One subprocess created.

Number of processes = 3

`fork()` for pid3: Two subprocesses created, one by original process and one by process pid2.

Number of processes = 5

`fork()` for pid4: One subprocess created.

Number of processes = 6

Comment: "Number of processes = 3" it is 4

Comment: One of the child processes has the same PID as the original parent.

Comment: Please draw a diagram